# Not able to see App_data folder in my MVC project in visual studio for mac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to learn MVC with EF on MacOS. I am using visual studio for mac and created an MVC project. I couldn't find App_Data folder under solution. please suggest how to get that. Also web.config file looks different compared to visual studio in windows. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can add it manually like we do in windows visual studio
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. I could see it when I click Add..->ASP.net Directory->App_data